# Request entity is too large posting adaptive card to WebHook

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to send an adaptive card with mentions in powershell using the following code:

```
    $bodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -Depth 8 @{
    type = "message"
    attachments = @(
       {
          contentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
          contentUrl = null
          content = {
             $"$schema" = "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
             type = "AdaptiveCard"
             version = "1.2"
             body = @(
                 {
                 type = "TextBlock",
                 text =  "Test <at>Irvin</at>"
                 }
             )
             msteams = {
              entities = @(
                {
                  type = "mention"
                  text = "<at>Irvin</at>"
                  mentioned = {
                    id = "myMail"
                    name = "Irvin Dominin"
                  }
                }
              )
            }
          }
       })       
    }

Invoke-RestMethod -uri $URITEST -Method Post -body $bodyJson -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

As response I'm getting:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The page was not displayed because the request
> entity is too large.
> Invoke-RestMethod -uri $URITEST -Method Post -body $bodyJson -Con ...
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod],
> WebException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

If I try to change the depth I'm getting:

> Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint
> returned HTTP error 413 with ContextId
> MS-CV=x1G81VkCIEWfRHXA/Qv5Aw.0..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing PowerShell and json syntax..

Did you by any chance mean

```
$bodyJson = ConvertTo-Json -Depth 8 @{
    type = "message"
    attachments = @(
       @{
          contentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
          contentUrl = $null
          content = @{
             schema = "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json"
             type = "AdaptiveCard"
             version = "1.2"
             body = @(
                 @{
                 type = "TextBlock"
                 text =  "Test <at>Irvin</at>"
                 }
             )
             msteams = @{
              entities = @(
                @{
                  type = "mention"
                  text = "<at>Irvin</at>"
                  mentioned = @{
                    id = "myMail"
                    name = "Irvin Dominin"
                  }
                }
              )
            }
          }
       })       
    }
```